# MySQL Inbox query returning double results

Tags: php, mysql, sms, message, message-queue

Using PHP and MySQL, I'm creating an inbox messaging system and it works, but it is returning doubles in a sense. The inbox should display a conversation between two people with the last message that was sent. The user can click on that latest message and chat with the user. Right now the inbox is showing the latest message sent by user 1 if user 1 messages user 2, AND it is showing the latest message if user 2 messaged user 1. If user 1 OR user 2 message each other, I just want to show the LAST message sent by either of them. Here is my query, I wanted to do this on my own, but my SQL skills have dulled a bit.

Here is my message table:
[image]

Here is my user table:
[image]

Lastly, here is the query:

```
SELECT m.body, m.createddate,m.recuserid,m.createduserid,
    FROM( SELECT MAX(createddate) as maxdate 
     from 

     messages 

     group by recuserid,createduserid
    ) c 
inner join messages m on m.createddate = c.maxdate 
inner join users u on u.userid = m.createduserid 

WHERE createduserid = 143 OR recuserid = 143
```

And here is the results that it returns:
[image]

As you can see, it returns any message that involves user 143 in any way. My desired results are to only return the 1st and 3rd row instead.

Comment: you're getting what you asked for. rows where createduserid is 143, **OR** where recuserid is 143.

Comment: @xQbert it returns the 3rd result but doesnt return the first one (me messaging myself)

Comment: @MarcB I realize this, but how do i fix it?

Comment: Remove `OR recuserID = 143`... and keep the group by, now that I see what your after...  though I would return both Ids and use them as part of the join criteria.

Comment: problem is that you're querying only for a date in the subquery, when you should be querying for a date AND userid,s o you can properly identify the parent record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
SELECT m.`body`,
       MAX(m.`createddate`) AS maxcreateddate,
       m.`pairid`
FROM (SELECT `body`,
             `createddate`,
             CONCAT(`recuserid`,`createduserid`) as pairid
      FROM `messages`
      WHERE `recuserid`=143
    UNION
      SELECT `body`,
             `createddate`,
             CONCAT(`createduserid`,`recuserid`) as pairid
      FROM `messages`
      WHERE `createduserid`=143) as m
GROUP BY pairid;
```

Someone might roast me about performance, but it does give you the result you're looking for (just the first and third rows).

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks man :) Amazing never seen someone use concat in that manner

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.body, m.createddate,m.recuserid,m.createduserid,
    FROM ( SELECT MAX(createddate) as Maxdate, recuserID, createduserId
           FROM MESSAGES 
           GROUP BY recuserid,createduserid) c 
INNER JOIN messages m 
   on m.createddate = c.Maxdate 
  and m.RecUserID = C.RecuserId
  and m.CreateduserId = C.CreatedUserId
INNER JOIN users u 
   on u.userid = m.createduserid 
WHERE createduserid = 143
```

The OR statement you have is what's causing the 2nd row to be returned. as @MarcB stated in initial comment.

However because of possible matches on date/time, you should return what you're grouping on and add it to the join criteria as well..

Maybe you just want the most recent message a user sent or received....

```
SELECT m.body, m.createddate,m.recuserid,m.createduserid,
    FROM ( SELECT MAX(createddate) as Maxdate,  
           FROM MESSAGES
           where createdUserID =143 OR RecUserID = 143) c 
INNER JOIN messages m 
   on m.createddate = c.Maxdate 
INNER JOIN users u 
   on u.userid = m.createduserid 
WHERE createduserid = 143
```

Comment: this works somewhat, but its not returning the latest message and instead the first?

Comment: What are you after?  the OLDest message or the NEWest?  This should return the NEWest message for each combination of recuserId and createduserId.

Comment: So you expect only 1 record to be returned the most recent message sent by either user, if A-->B or B-->A or A-->A. but only 1?  if so then why the comment, "My desired results are to only return the 1st and 3rd row instead.?"  I'm at a loss I don't know what your expected results are.

Comment: Sorry if I was vague in any way but yes I am looking for the most recent message a user sent or received . And by 1st and third row I meant from the results picture i posted in the OP. The desired results should look like just row 1 and 3, not row 2 included. If you look at the time attached to each message, row 2 and 3 are both conversations between the same people, but the 3rd row has a latter time than the 2nd, so it should not display 2 and instead just display 3

Comment: I'm baffled...   How can "Most recent Message return 2 results unless they are the same date/time?  which is clearly not the case for both 1 and 3.  So the expected results you're looking for don't match the English being used.   Until you clear up the expected results, or the English question I don't know what to do here.

Comment: I don't want 2 results, only 1. Where did I say I wanted 2 results?

Comment: you want records 1 and 3... that's two records. If you really are after the most recent message for a user (sent or received), my second query  should do it.  I'm going to take a step back breathe and look over it all again.  Maybe I'm missing something simple.  Where I"m confused are these two statements which seem contrary to me, "I just want to show the LAST message sent by either of them" and "My desired results are to only return the 1st and 3rd row instead."  LAST message and 1st and 3rd rows ... 1 record vs 2 records.  I think you want one but your expected results show 2.

Comment: When I said records 1 and 3, I was referring to the rows in the image i linked http://i.stack.imgur.com/D7F5C.png. 143-143 and 143-144. I was just giving an example of what the output of the query based on the tables I gave you were supposed to represent. It's still 1 record involving 143 and 144. Ignore 143-143 for now.  Basically, how do I get rid of that 2nd row on http://i.stack.imgur.com/D7F5C.png while keeping the others??

Comment: "How do I get rid of that 2nd row on i.stack.imgur.com/D7F5C.png while keeping the others?? – "  ANSWER: Change from `WHERE createduserid = 143 OR recuserid = 143` to `WHERE recuserid = 143`  the Or Condition is bringing in the 2nd record. AND evaluate the inner select.  I don't think it's doing what you hope.  I suspect it is returning 1 record for each pairing of sender/receiver, which would eliminate all but the most recent records except for the fact that if users had the same createdDate, you may get multiple results.

Comment: That isn't a solution to it -_- and I am not worried about the createddate for right now... Ill just work on it on my own